# Xamdatagrid howto get the current Cell on right click

Tags: cell, xamdatagrid, right-click

here is the scenario I want ta achieve on some XamDataGrid

1. Some Cells may be selected in the grid - cells  and not records
2. User right clicks on a cell in the grid

I would like to add the right clicked cell to the SelectedItems.Cells collection of the XamDataGrid if it was not selected before

BTW - I have no problem getting the entire Record, but what I require is the specific Cell.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void GridCellActivated(object sender, CellActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((UnboundField)((e.Cell).Field)).BindingPath.Path != null)
    {
      var _fieldPath = ((UnboundField) ((e.Cell).Field)).BindingPath.Path;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Note for potential readers: this only works on the first click.